# bbCode in an another

Tags: php, html, regex, bbcode

I made a custom function which acts like bbCode. I'm using preg_replace and regex. The only problem is that if I use more than one bbCode formatting, then just only one works..

```
[align=center][img]myimagelink[/img][/align]
```

If I enter this line, then the image appears BUT the [align=center]*image*[/align] also. How can I avoid this problem?

```
$patterns[2] = '@\[align=(.*)\](.*)\[\/align\]@si';
$patterns[9] = '@\[img\](.*\.jpg)\[\/img\]@si';
$replacements[2] = '<table align=\1><tr><td align=\1>\2</td></tr></table>';//ALIGN
$replacements[9] = '<img src=\"$1\"/>';//image
```

Comment: Your patterns are greedy, so the `[align]` will match things like `[align=something[/align][/align]`.

Comment: i would search and replace the image as is, BUT paired tags like 'align' as singles ie treat [align=center] and [/align] as seperate entities. so the replace wont include the code between the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `.*` expressions to non-greedy (`.*?`) will work for you.

Example:

```
$in = '[align=center][img]myimagelink[/img][/align]';
$patterns = array(
    '~\[align=(left|right|center)\](.*?)\[/align\]~' => '<div style="text-align: $1">$2</div>',
    '~\[img](.*?)\[/img\]~' => '<img src="$1" />',
);

$rep = preg_replace(array_keys($patterns), $patterns, $in);
echo htmlspecialchars($rep);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinventing the wheel I recommend using an existing javascript library.

I believe StackOverflow uses [**Prettify**](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to format user input.

Answer (score 0):

As @nickb stated, your patterns are greedy. `(.*)` grabs everything. Try changing it to `(.*?)`.

Answer (score 0):

treat all tags as singles not pairs

```
$patterns[2] = '@\[align=(.*)\]@si';
$patterns[3] = '@\[\/align\]@si';
$patterns[9] = '@\[img\](.*\.jpg)\[\/img\]@si';
$replacements[2] = '<div align=\"$1\">';//ALIGN
$replacements[3] = '</div>';//ALIGN
$replacements[9] = '<img src=\"$1\"/>';//image
```